# A better way than attaching multiple event handlers to elements in the DOM

Tags: jquery, hover, event-handling

I am currently thinking about some efficiency/speed issues.

I have about 40 a elements and divs nested in li´s

```
<ul id=ul>  
<li><a href="#">Link</a><div>Text</div></li>  
<li><a href="#">Link</a><div>Text</div></li>  
<li><a href="#">Link</a><div>Text</div></li>  
<li><a href="#">Link</a><div>Text</div></li>  
<li><a href="#">Link</a><div>Text</div></li>  
....   
</ul>
```

On all the li´s I have hover events attached

```
$('#ul li').hover(function(e){
    $(this).children(div).show();},
function(){
    $(this).children(div).hide();
})
```

I was wondering if there was a better way than attaching 40 event handlers to the dom for a hover event. I think this can be slow in some browsers.

I heard about DOM traversing, like when you put only ONE handler on the #ul container and let dom traversing inside the browser (e.target) figure out what element has been hoverd. Anybody know how to approach this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.delegate()` does what you describe:

```
$('#ul').delegate('li', 'mouseenter', function (e) {...});
$('#ul').delegate('li', 'mouseleave', function (e) {...});
```

Note that `.hover()` is just a shortcut for the two events, mouseenter and mouseleave, hence the two calls to `.degelate()` above.

Even though `.delegate()` is called on `$('#ul')`, `$(this)` will refer to the `<li>` element inside the events handlers.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really want is to use jQuery's [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS to show/hide the divs instead:

```
#ul li div
{
    display: none;
}  

#ul li:hover div
{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `display: block` and to add a `#ul li div {display: none}`?